# How does a WPF ResourceDictionary Work? (I can't get mine to load.)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, resourcedictionary

I coded up a custom assembly that lets me view my Prism Regions at Design Time.

One of the things my assembly does is that it will load the assembly from the startup project.  (Using Prism's module catalog.)

For a simple app it works **great**.

But when I tried to put it in my real app it breaks the design time view (run time works fine).

It says that it can't find the file that contains a ResourceDictionary my project uses.
It also says it can't find one of the assemblies used by that ResourceDictionary.

My *guess* is that pulling the assembly from the startup location is causing this problem.

But this does not make sense to me because of the following reasons:

1. The ResourceDictionary is loaded in my view like this:

   ```
   <UserControl.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary>
       <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
           <ResourceDictionary Source="/DataProviders.xaml"/>
       </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
     ...
   ```

   but the file that loads it is not included in the output.  So it must be compiled into the dll.
   That leads me to think that this should work:

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyProj;component/DataProviders.xaml" />
   ```

   But that does not work either.  (I tried it with and without the slash.)
2. If it a location issue (because I am loading from the start project rather than the output location (bin\debug), then how come it can't find the other assembly that it thinks it is missing?
   .
   That assembly is in the output folder for both projects (startup and the project in question).
3. Figuring it was the location, I tried an absolute path in the source.  Like this:

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary Source="C:/src/solution/Regns/MyProj/DataProviders.xaml"/>
   ```

   and that did not work either.  (It still said that it cannot find the resource file.)

In thinking about this, I have decided that I don't know enough about how ResourceDictionarys work.

Can anyone enlighten me as to why my ResourceDictionary will not load.

Comment: Try this: `pack://application:,,,/MyProj;component/DataProviders.xaml`

Comment: @Douglas, Good idea, but alas, it did not work.

Comment: Read Pack URI resolution: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069#Pack_URI_Resolution ("URI resolution does not apply for URIs that refer to ... Content files in referenced assemblies: these file types are not supported by WPF").

Comment: Also, I believe I read somewhere that the ResourceDictionary Source property only supports Relative Pack URIs. I cannot find documentation to back that up, though.

Answer (score 2):

The application has a "central" `ResourceDictionary`, which you can access via [`Application.Current.Resources`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.resources.aspx).  If you have additional resources that you want to load out of other assemblies, then in your application startup you need to merge all the dictionaries from your external assemblies with the main resource dictionary from your application and set the `Application.Current.Resources` property to that set of merged dictionaries.

I found this link on code project that might help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35346/Using-a-Resource-Dictionary-in-WPF

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to load your resource dictionary at run time. I have a post that I think answers your question:

[How to load a DictionaryStyle.xaml file at run time?](http://www.wpfsharp.com/2012/01/26/how-to-load-a-dictionarystyle-xaml-file-at-run-time/)

Comment: Hmmm, it works fine at run time.  It is at Design Time that it can't find the file.

Comment: I have an article on that too.
How to load a ResourceDictionary at Design Time in WPF
http://www.wpfsharp.com/2012/02/02/how-to-load-a-resourcedictionary-at-design-time-in-wpf/